# How to fix "NameError: name 'default' is not defined"?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm setting up a simple database using flask and SQLalchemy, but the attributes I'm setting up for my classes don't recognize the "default" name.

I'm using Python 3.7.4, Flask 1.1.1, and Flask-SQLALchemy 2.4. I've tried reinstalling SQLAlchemy, and double-checking my syntax.

Here are my the modules I'm using:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, flash, redirect
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime
from forms import Registrationform, Loginform, BudgetEntry
```

and here's one of my classes

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False, unique=True)
    image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default=default.jpg)
    password = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    budgets = db.relationship("Budget", backref="author", lazy=True)
```

Now when I go into the command line and try to import db, it gives me an error:

```
NameError: name 'default' is not defined
```

Comment: Your title ("default" is not defined) is at odds with the claimed error ("db" is not defined)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and if you get errors, provide the full error stack.

Comment: Seems like `db` is indeed not defined. So, you should probably define it.

Comment: Looks like the [Flask-SQLAlchemy quickstart guide](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/quickstart/) shows how you should define `db`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If (as your **title** claims) you are getting the error *'default' is not defined* then it is because currently you have:

```
image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default=default.jpg)
```

Presumably you are wanting

```
image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default="default.jpg")
```